# Error[Pe513]: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "uint8_t *"

Tags: c++, c, embedded, iar

I am attempting to convert a C project into C++.

In the C project I countered this error while compiling into c++:

> Error[Pe513]: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "uint8_t *"

The following code gives this error:

```
#define RAM32Boundary  0x20007D00
uint8_t *pNextRam;
pNextRam = (void*)RAM32Boundary;// load up the base ram
```

Can anyone explain what this is doing in C and how to convert it into C++?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C allows implicit conversions to/from `void*`, which C++ does not.  You need to cast to the *correct* type.

Use:

```
uint8_t *pNextRam;
pNextRam = (uint8_t*)RAM32Boundary;// load up the base ram
```

Or **better still***, use a C++ style cast instead of C style.:

```
uint8_t *pNextRam;
pNextRam = static_cast<uint8_t*>(RAM32Boundary);// load up the base ram
```

*In practice, casting is an easy source of bugs.  C++ style casts allow a reader of your code to easily see a cast *and* allow the compiler to enforce the correctness of your cast.